Estimate the derivative of solutions of the heat equation
Consider $u$ solving the following heat equation
\begin{cases}
\partial_t u = \Delta u + f & \text{in } \mathbb R^2 \times \mathbb R^+, \\
u(\cdot, 0) = 0 &   \text{in } \mathbb R^2,
\end{cases}
with $f \in L^\infty(\mathbb R^2 \times \mathbb R^+).$ I was wondering if there was a way to prove that for any $R > 0$, we could show the following estimate
$$\|\nabla u\|_{L^\infty(Q_{R/2}(t_0, x_0))} \le \frac{1}{R}\left(\|f\|_{L^\infty(Q_{R}(t_0, x_0))} + \|u\|_{L^\infty(Q_{R}(t_0, x_0))}\right),$$
where the cylinder $Q_R$ is defined by
$$Q_R(t_0, x_0) = \{(t,x) ~|~ |x - x_0| \le R, ~ t_0 - R^2 \le t \le t_0\}.$$
This type of interior estimate for the derivative is well known for the Poisson problem, i.e. $\Delta u = f$, but does it still hold when we consider the heat equation ?
I saw in Evan's book that we had such inequality when $f = 0$, but the proof strongly uses the mean value formula which is, as far as I know, valid only when $f = 0$. Is there any way to solve this question for the heat equation ?

$f$ being merely $L^{\infty}$ makes a direct application of the Green function formula difficult: $u(x,t) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} G(x-y, t) f(y) dy$ where $G(\cdot, t)$ is the Gaussian kernel at $t$. Since you only care about a local (in time) and interior estimate, I suggest mollify the solution to be more tamable and start working from there.
